# What is the idea of shell in monolithic Kernel

Tags: linux-kernel

From definition of `monolithic kernel`, it says that it exists as single bin file in an address location, and it varies from micro-kernel in a sense that in micro-kernel, there are servers which run in kernel and user-space.

My question here is that shell interprets the user commands for the kernel, so does it mean shell exists in the user-space ?

If yes isn't the interaction between kernel and shell just like it happens in micro-kernel using message passing ?

So how does micro-kernel differ from monolithic kernel ?

Answer (score 0):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monolithic_kernel see the image it give you clear picture.

It is NOT about kernel and u-space application interaction.

In micro-k let say you are reading a file then file-system server comes into the picture. user send request to file system server but to read a file from device you need driver so file system server must have to  communicate with  device drivers server (message passing occurs between two core functionality of OS file system and device driver)

In case of Mono-kernel everything (like file system , device drivers so on) is part of kernel and it is single-flow no message between kernels subsystems like file systems and device drivers.

You can find other major difference in the link  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microkernel